# Почему не работает JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем ошибка. В консоли ошибок нет.

```
$("#accordion h3").click(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: @Grundy, каким боком это дубликат?

Comment: @Yuri, прямым, `this` - ожидается что это элемент по которому кликнули, в вопросе по ссылке объясняется почему это не так, и показаны варианты решения

Answer (score 0):

У вас `this` - это сам таймер. Что бы передать "себя же" в таймер используйте переменную:

```
$("#accordion h3").click(function () {
  var e = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(e).toggleClass('active');
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: this - это сам таймер ???

Comment: @Igor, на самом деле зависит от окружения, а nodejs например может быть и таймером

Comment: Yuri, спасибо. Помогло)